# Service Agreement + Temporary License Agreement?

Tags: licensing, software

If two companies (Customer & Supplier) enter into a Master Service Agreement (complemented with a separate Statement of Work for each Individual Project), but the MSA does not contain any provision granting any license to Supplier test and develop SW based on existing source code, how can this be tackled?

Let's say (to make things more complicated a bit) that Customer is not the owner of that source code but rather a subsidiary entity of the owner of IP.

Does it make sense to prepare a separate Temporary License Agreement for test and development purposes between IP owner and Supplier?